# Map an array of strings to an array of objects

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am trying to do something fairly simple - given an array strings as input I want to get an array of objects with specified attributes like

```
const summaryAggFields = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'];
const summaryAggFieldMap = lodash.map(summaryAggFields, f =>  {field: f, aggregate: 'sum'});
```

`summaryAggFieldMap`  should be be like `[{field:'f1', aggregate: 'sum'}, ...]`

What is the correct way to do this?
Thanks
Anand

Comment: For such a simple task you don't need lodash: `summaryAggFields.map(f => ({...}))`

Comment: @Andreas thanks so much!